# highlight text within lstlisting

Tags: listings, highlighting

I would like to highlight some text in a lstlisting section. The text contains some characters like % and {, }.

To highlight some code I use different method but I always have the same issue:

```
    \begin{lstlisting}[
    basicstyle=\small,
    frame=single,   
        breaklines=true,
        postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space},
        escapeinside ={\%,},
    escapechar={!},
    caption={Configuration de l'hôte virtuel dans \emph{Apache} après installation des certificats avec CertBot.},
    label={codeA3.A}
    ]
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName apache.labo.XX
    ServerAlias www.apache.labo.XX
    DocumentRoot /var/www/apache.labo.XX/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/apache.labo.XX/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/apache.labo.XX/log/requests.log combined
!\hl{RewriteEngine on}!
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =apache.labo.XX [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.apache.labo.XX
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
\end{lstlisting}
```

I get the good result

[image]

But If I want to highlight the 3 lines below, the ones starting by "Rewrite" I have an issue. It's not working.

It's probably I have to escape the characters % and {, } but I can't figure out how to do it.

Can you please help me ,

Thanks !

Comment: \ escapes: \% \{ \ _ \} \^ etc. Assuming you are using `soul` and `listings` packages: `!\hl{RewriteCond \%\{SERVER\_NAME\} =apache.labo.XX [OR]}!`

Comment: If I do \% the character \ is printed in lstlisting

Comment: It works now with the escapeinside. But not the content escapeinside={\%,\%,\{,\},\_,\^},

Is displayed on the screen

Comment: OK had to create a line escapeinside=\% etc for each case.

Comment: \ works OK for me; I did nothing extra. The manual `texdoc listings`, p 40 says **4.3.13 Escaping to LATEX**: "Note that TEX’s special characters must be entered with a preceding backslash...". You haven't supplied an MWE so I can't comment on what your code is doing because I haven't seen it. Guessing is insufficient. Note that `%` is Latex's special-character for starting Latex comments. Anyway, glad that it sounds like you solved it.